# In the Wordpress.org admin panel, where can I find the page showing the recommended settings of the theme I'm using?

Tags: wordpress, themes, settings

When I first started building this new website using wordress.org and MAMP, I noticed a page that showed all the recommended settings for a particular theme I'm using.

For example, recommended memory & ram, compatibility issues with plugins, SSL certificate reminder, etc etc

I can't seem to find it, and it is really frustrating me! I've searched every page. There were a few things that were on it I now can't remember which I needed to do. It was a checklist I needed.

I found an about theme page under appearance, but that's only showing very limited recommended settings. Before there were 5 times more. Not sure if there's a different page or its the same but its showing less recommended settings.

Any help pointing me to where it is located is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The page I was looking for was system status under the woo commerce menu tab.